# MySQL Connector C API Unable to connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, c, sockets

I am attempting to connect to a MySQL database setup by [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) using the [MySQL Connector C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-c.html) on OSX. Using this code:

```
MYSQL mysql;
mysql_init(&mysql);
if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","root","",NULL,0,NULL,0))
{
    printf("Failed to connect to database: Error (%d): %s",mysql_errno(&mysql),mysql_error(&mysql));
}
else printf("Connection success!");
```

I get the following result:

```
Failed to connect to database: Error (2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can confirm the database is operational because phpMyAdmin connects to it fine, here is the config.inc.php file:

```
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Does anyone know why phpMyAdmin can connect but my C program cannot? I have tried forcing TCP/IP connections to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the default port 3306
mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","root","",NULL,3306,NULL,0)

or reconfig the my.cnf (suppose you use linux) and restart mysql.

```
[mysqld]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Thank you, it turns out XAMPP changes the socket MySQL listens on, after finding the my.cnf it states the path to the socket.

Comment: Tried using port 3306 as you suggested. Did not work.